# Entity Frame work insert to SQL db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

[image: A frame from my code block]

I want to use `Public Override OnModelCreating(DBMod ...)`

But there is no `OnModelCreating` method in a popup window as you can see on the picture and I need to use it. Please help what is wrong in my code block?

Comment: mmm can you write  a your Method lile  awrapper and then call base. OnModelCreating() ?

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework are you working on?

Comment: ı use .Net Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`protected override` ...
Since the access modifier of the method is `Protected` not `Public`.

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense does not work here.
Just write it:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ....
}
```